# Pythonic alternative to R's vectorized functions

Tags: python, loops, vectorization

I'm working in Python, but coming from an R background - where, if I want to take an array of strings `x = ['1', '2', '3']` and get the corresponding array of integers `[1, 2, 3]`, the natural thing to do would be to run something like `int(x)`. Of course, this syntax doesn't work because I'm in Python and functions aren't automatically vectorized. Seems like I can maybe use NumPy to create a vectorized version of functions, but that feels like speaking Python in a very heavy R accent.

Looping over the contents of the vector works

```
x2 = []
for y in x:
    x2.append(int(y))
```

but doesn't seem at all elegant - it's a three line construction for something I could do in six characters in R. Surely there's a Pythonic way to do this that's more compact? Or is this butting up against the respective strengths and weaknesses of Python vs. R?

Comment: Search for "python list comprehension"

Comment: There's a reason Python calls them "lists" and not "vectors".  Numpy is absolutely the way to go if what you want to do is vectorized numerical operations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either use `map`

```
>>> lst = ['1', '2', '3']
>>> map(int, lst)
[1, 2, 3]
```

or a list comprehension:

```
>>> [int(x) for x in lst]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Which one to use? Primarily opinion based. Personally, I prefer `map` if the function that is mapped already exists as a built-in.

Note that in Python3, `map` will yield a map object, which - if you want to have a list - you would have to cast to list explicitly. So the comprehension is probably preferred in Python3:

```
>>> result = map(int, ['1', '2', '3'])
>>> result
<map object at 0x7f35c4c3af98>
>>> list(result)
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 5):

You should use the [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/) library, and possibly other libraries based on it, like [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/).  If what you want to do is vectorized numerical operations, these are the way to do it.

You're right in a way that you're bumping up against the strengths and weaknesses of the two languages.  In R everything is a vector, even single numeric values.  This makes vectorized operations easy but can make it awkward to do anything where you *don't* want vectorized numerical computations.  Python has greater flexibility by virtue of not building things like vectorization into the core language types; you can still do it, but you need a library

In other words, a strength of R is that everything is vectorized and a weakness is that everything is vectorized; a strength of Python is that things are not vectorized by default and a weakness is that things are not vectorized by default.  Using numpy to do vectorized operations isn't so much "Python with an R accent" as "Python with a vector accent", which is exactly what you want if you want vectorized operations.  If you're doing a lot of stats, you may find R's strengths helpful.  In my experience, if you're doing almost anything but stats, you'll find Python much more adaptable to a variety of tasks.

Answer (score 3):

You could use list comprehension:

```
x = ['1', '2', '3']
l = [int(i) for i in x]
print(l)
[1, 2, 3]
```

If you are going to use something complex with vectors, dataframes you should check [`numpy`](http://www.numpy.org/), [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) and [`scipy`](http://scipy.org/) libraries.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend using `numpy` for working with vector data. That's exactly what it is there for. It's a very mature library, widely used by other libraries and has nothing to do with "speaking Python in a very heavy R accent".

An alternative for this particular example would be a list comprehension:

```
[int(e) for e in x]
```